# Express JS how to include node-mysql object from a different file

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I want to include my mysql connection from the same file(in case I have to change sql password or anything I don't want to change in a many files).

Here is my mysql.js file:

```
module.exports = require('mysql').createConnection(
  {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'admin',
      password : 'xxxxxxxx',
      database : 'database'
  }

);
```

and I want to use like this:

```
var connection = require(__dirname + '/../../../mysql');
connection.connect();
.
.
.
```

My problem is it's working only once. When I start the server I can query without any issues, but in the second query I got the following error message in the console:

```
"Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
```

Does anybody has an idea why not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the help, but I found a solution for my problem. I just created the variables on my mysql.js file then I exported them like this:

```
var host = 'localhost';
module.exports.localhost = localhost;
```

After I can use it on another js file:

```
var connection = require(__dirname + '/../../../mysql');

connection.localhost;
```

I found it on this article:
http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you no longer need to call connect() after createConnection(), it'll be handled for you on query, if you like.

From the docs:

> However, a connection can also be implicitly established by invoking a
>   query:
>
> var mysql      = require('mysql'); 
>      var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);
>
> connection.query('SELECT 1', function(err, rows) {   // connected!
>       (unless `err` is set) });
>
> Depending on how you like to handle your
>   errors, either method may be appropriate. Any type of connection error
>   (handshake or network) is considered a fatal error, see the Error
>   Handling section for more information.

Other than that, you may be calling connect() before calling end() on the same connection, you might want to check for that.